# Azure Pipelines: Error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier android was not recognized

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a .NET MAUI mobile app project and since yesterday it was built ok in Azure DevOps until yesterday.

Then I start getting this error:

> Error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier android was not
> recognized

I have specified target platform as `net7.0-android` in my csproj file.

```xml
 <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
```

Upon executing this task

```yaml
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        displayName: "Performing NuGet restore"
        inputs:          
          command: restore
          VstsFeed: "xxx.xxxx/Lib"
```

Nuget restore has called after `dotnet restore` that executed ok.

```yaml
      - task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
        displayName: "NuGet Authenticate"

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: "Performing DotNet Restore"
        inputs:
          command: restore
          feedsToUse: 'select'
          VstsFeed: "xxx.xxxx/Lib"

      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        displayName: "Performing NuGet restore"
        inputs:          
          command: restore
          VstsFeed: "xxx.xxxx/Lib"
```

I suppose the windows agent image is missing some workloads now.

I install workloads using the following command:

```yaml
      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: "Install MAUI support"
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
                    dotnet nuget locals all --clear
                    dotnet workload install maui
                    dotnet workload install maui-mobile
                    dotnet workload install android 
                    dotnet workload install maui-android
```

And when I call

> dotnet workload list

It shows that the following workloads are installed:

| Installed Workload Id | Manifest Version | Installation Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| android | 33.0.68/7.0.100 | SDK 7.0.400 |
| maui | 7.0.92/7.0.100 | SDK 7.0.400 |
| maui-android | 7.0.92/7.0.100 | SDK 7.0.400 |
| maui-mobile | 7.0.92/7.0.100 | SDK 7.0.400 |

Then I called the command

> dotnet workload search

To list all available workloads and get this list:

| Workload ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| android | .NET SDK Workload for building Android applications. |
| ios | .NET SDK Workload for building iOS applications. |
| maccatalyst | .NET SDK Workload for building MacCatalyst applications. |
| macos | .NET SDK Workload for building macOS applications. |
| maui | .NET MAUI SDK for all platforms |
| maui-android | .NET MAUI SDK for Android |
| maui-desktop | .NET MAUI SDK for Desktop |
| maui-ios | .NET MAUI SDK for iOS |
| maui-maccatalyst | .NET MAUI SDK for Mac Catalyst |
| maui-mobile | .NET MAUI SDK for Mobile |
| maui-tizen | .NET MAUI SDK for Tizen |
| maui-windows | .NET MAUI SDK for Windows |
| runtimes-windows | workloads/runtimes-windows/description |
| runtimes-windows-net6 | workloads/runtimes-windows-net6/description |
| tvos | .NET SDK Workload for building tvOS applications. |
| wasm-experimental | workloads/wasm-experimental/description |
| wasm-tools | .NET WebAssembly build tools |
| wasm-tools-net6 | .NET WebAssembly build tools |

What workload should I install to fix this issue?

I tried to install `runtimes-windows` workload too, but it did not help.

Comment: This is a known issue on .Net MAUI, Refer the comments in these 2 github issues 1) https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14206 > You can specify the -f switch with the TFM you want to build specifically. For instance: dotnet build -f net7.0-ios. If you have a net7.0 in there, you should be able to just to dotnet build -f net7.0. 2) https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8072 You probably want to either uninstall that or use a global.json file indeed to make sure that your app uses .NET 6 which is needed by .NET MAUI right now.

Also see https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/.NET-7-and-.NET-MAUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have seen the same issue (starting only yesterday). We found that the reason was the update of the SDK version from 7.0.306 to 7.0.400. This update was done automatically in the build pipeline (and probably in yours as well).
Using the suggestion from SiddheshDesai we created a global.json to hardcode the SDK version to the previously working version:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "7.0.306",
    "rollForward": "disable"
  }
}
```

This workaround allowed building again. However, this is just a temporary workaround and it should be reverted once the issue is fixed.